# Clear MUI Select value after submitting form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to clear my Select values from MUI after I submit a form, but the values aren't being cleared.

```
<form action = {(event) => calculateCaloricIntake(event)}>
<FormControl>
                <InputLabel>Height in Inches</InputLabel>
                <Select required onChange = {(event) => setHeightInches(event.target.value)} sx = {{width : 150}}>
                    <MenuItem value = {1}>1</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {2}>2</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {3}>3</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {4}>4</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {5}>5</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {6}>6</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {7}>7</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {8}>8</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {9}>9</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {10}>10</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {11}>11</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
                 
            <FormControl>
                 <InputLabel>Activity Level</InputLabel>
                    <Select required onChange = {(event) => setActivityLevel(event.target.value)} sx = {{width : 150}}>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.2}>Sedentary</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.375}>Slightly Active</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.55} >Moderately Active</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.725}>Very Active</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.9}>Extremely Active</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
     </FormControl>
</form>
```

This is an example of one of the MUI Selects that I have in my code. everything would be enclosed uner the a form tag.

```
    const calculateCaloricIntake = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setCalorieIntake(CalculateCalories(sex, age, userWeight, heighFeet, heightInches, activityLevel, calorieIntake));   
    event.target.reset();
}
```

This is what is being called in the form onSubmit. All of the select state's are being stored using hooks. I've tried using event.target.reset() but that only works for the text fields that I have. What would be my best approach?

Comment: You can use "value" in <Select> to set the current value. And, "defaultValue" to set the default. You can read it more here: 
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't help solve the issue. I've tried doing setHeightInches(0) where the form is behing handled, but that also doesn't work.